# Updating a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following list of lists:

```
MyList = [[130, 10], [131, 15], [132, 1]]
```

Then i have some inputs. If i get, for example: `Data = [130, 3], [135, 10]`, i need to update the list like this:

```
MyList = [[130, 3], [131, 15], [132, 1], [135, 10]]
```

So, if in `MyList` there is already a sublist where the first element is the same as the first element of a sublist in `Data`, update the same element. Instead, if there isn't one, append it.

I managed to do this but i was wondering if there was a cleaner solution, as i really don't like the actual one:

```
Temp = [x[0] for x in MyList]

for x in Data:
    if x[0] not in Temp:
        Sublist = []
        Sublist.append(x[0])
        Sublist.append(x[1])
        MyList.append(Sublist)
    else:
        for y in MyList:
            if x[0] == y[0]:
                x[1] = y[1]
```

Is there any better way to do this? I feel like this code can be improved, i also don't like editing elements while looping. Any kind of help is welcome!

Comment: I think the code you have is the most efficient it can be, sorry for the unhelpfulness

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If not, please clarify the problem with a [mre].

Comment: you could avoid problems if `dict` was used

Comment: A cleaner solution would be to not use a `list`, probably better of with a dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cleanest solution would be to use a `dict` to begin with. So,

```
>>> data = dict([[130, 10], [131, 15], [132, 1]])
>>> data
{130: 10, 131: 15, 132: 1}
>>> for x, y in [130, 3], [135, 10]:
...     data[x] = y
...
>>> data
{130: 3, 131: 15, 132: 1, 135: 10}
```

If you really need a list at the end:

```
>>> list(data.items())
[(130, 3), (131, 15), (132, 1), (135, 10)]
```

Or even just:

```
>>> data = {130: 10, 131: 15, 132: 1}
>>> new_data = [130, 3], [135, 10]
>>> data.update(new_data)
>>> data
{130: 3, 131: 15, 132: 1, 135: 10}
```

Comment: i think that, indeed, using a dict is the best way to go here, rather than a list. Thank you!

Comment: @Jack022 yes, one of the most important considerations for clean code is to choose the right data structures that allow you to write the code cleanly in the first place

Comment: One last thing: wouldn't i get the same output here using the update() method?

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution (if you insist to use lists instead of the preferred structure dictionary) might be:

```
MyList = [item for item in MyList if item[0] not in [i[0] for i in Data]]
MyList.extend(Data)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your this question, what you can do is extend your main list with all 
the data, and then use dict operation to make a dictionary

```
MyList = [[130, 10], [131, 15], [132, 1]]


new_data = [[130, 3], [135, 10]]

MyList.extend(new_data)

final_data=  dict(MyList)
print(final_data)
# {130: 3, 131: 15, 132: 1, 135: 10}
```

Comment: this isn't a clean way to use a dict at all. There's no need to check `if a in my_dic.keys()`, and even if there were, you should use `if x in my_dict`.  In any case, that is pointless, because you *always* do `my_dic.update({a:b})`, which is also not a clean way of doing that, that should just be `my_dic[a] = b`

Answer (score 0):

If I got your problem right, this is what I have in mind, similar to yours.

```
myList = [[130, 10], [131, 15], [132, 1]]
data = [130, 3], [135, 10]

if data[0][0] == myList[0][0]:
    myList.pop(0)
    myList.insert(0, data[0])
    myList = myList + list(data[1:])
else:
    myList = myList + list(data)

print(myList)
```

output:

```
[[130, 3], [131, 15], [132, 1], [135, 10]]
```